# Azure Devops Server 2019 Backup testing

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, azure-devops, azure-devops-server

I have created backups using Azure DevOps server 2019 so I want to test the integrity of those backups. by testing I mean check that the backups are valid. I can't check them manually because of the huge amount of data so I thought about a hash function or something like that. if there is any tool or solution that may help or if there's any tool integrated in Azure DevOps server 2019 that does it automatically let me know and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing some checksums is not a restore test.

Restore databases for real. Prepare (test) database servers. Restore data, timing how long it takes. Connect test application servers, if available.

[An outline of such a restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance?view=azure-devops-2019) is in Azure DevOps Server documentation, although details likely need customization to your environment. In particular, whether the [restore wizard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-restore-dbs?view=azure-devops-2019) can handle some details for you:

> If you manually configured your backups, you cannot use the Restore
> wizard in Scheduled Backups to restore those databases. You must
> manually restore them using the software you used to back them up.

Unfortunately, restore of a general purpose, multiple tier, database application like this can be a bit of work. Encourage leadership to do restores regularly, at least on major infrastructure changes like a new backup system.

Comment: so the short-term solution is to restore data and check, and the long-term one is a new backup system. am I right? if so do you have any suggestions ? 
Thank you

Comment: Regularly restore data to improve confidence in your recovery procedures. There is no one button to push that automates documenting the process, the restore itself, and the report on whether you meet your recovery time objectives.